Relationship in repeater field
I’m following this tutorial and I try to apply it to my website.
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/
I have artists thats plays in places.
An artist can play in different places, so i want to compare the row of the repeater field with the current place ID. And only show the row where the place is the same that the page.
But i don’t know how to achieve it…
Anyone can help me ?
Thanks
Here is the code for the place : single-place.php
<?php
function allow_wildcards($where)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $where = str_replace(
        "meta_key = 'representation_%",
        "meta_key LIKE 'representation_%",
        $wpdb->remove_placeholder_escape($where)
    );

    return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'allow_wildcards');
?>
<?php
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'artiste',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'representation_%_lieu_representation',
            'value' => '"'.get_the_ID().'"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
));
?>
<?php if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php if (have_rows('representation')): while (have_rows('representation')) : the_row(); ?>
        <p>
            <?php $date_rep = get_sub_field('date_representation'); ?>
            <?php echo $date_rep; ?><?php the_title(); ?>
        </p>
    <?php endwhile; else : endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; else: endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


Have you inspected the result of last_query to see if it is what you expected?

With this code it shows all the date of the artists, even in the other places of concert ! And i only want to show the places that correspond to the single page !

Can you post the last_query?

Here it is :
mardi 15 octobre 2024 19:00Le Chant Traditionnel en Haute Bretagne
mercredi 16 octobre 2024 18:00Le Chant Traditionnel en Haute Bretagne
dimanche 20 octobre 2024 19:00Le Chant Traditionnel en Haute Bretagne
jeudi 17 octobre 2024 19:00An Eagle In Your Mind
vendredi 18 octobre 2024 18:00An Eagle In Your Mind
samedi 19 octobre 2024 20:00An Eagle In Your Mind

That looks like results, not the actual SQL query

I removed the repeater tag because the description refers to an ASP.net control.

I found the solution ! Thanks
<?php 
    function allow_wildcards( $where ) {global $wpdb;
    $where = str_replace("meta_key = 'representation_%", "meta_key LIKE 'representation_%",
    $wpdb->remove_placeholder_escape($where)
    );return $where;}
    add_filter('posts_where', 'allow_wildcards');
    ?>  
        
    <?php 
    $query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'artiste',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'meta_key'  => 'representation_%_lieu_representation',
            'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"', 
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
        )
    ));
        
    $current_lieu_ID = get_the_ID();    
    ?>

    <?php if($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>
        
        <?php if( have_rows('representation') ): while( have_rows('representation') ) : the_row();?>
        
        <p>
            <?php $lieu_rep = get_sub_field('lieu_representation'); ?>
            <?php $date_rep = get_sub_field('date_representation'); ?>
            <?php $lieu_rep_ID = $lieu_rep[0];?>
            <?php if ($current_lieu_ID == $lieu_rep_ID) : ?>
                <?php echo $date_rep; ?><br/><?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php endif;?>  
        </p>
        
        <?php endwhile; else :endif; ?>
        
    <?php endwhile; else: endif; wp_reset_postdata();?> 


While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.
